# Sum in Access Producing Total Sum and Placing This on Each Row

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to create two columns: IntlAir and DomesticAir. I have a Boolean column in my data called `International`, and IntlAir returns `Penalty + SellingFare` when `International` is `TRUE`, and DomAir returns that sum when `International = FALSE`.

I would like to show this amount for each DK by Month.

My code is:

```
SELECT data.PostingMonth, data.DK_Number
     , (SELECT sum(data.Penalty + data.SellingFare)
        FROM data
        WHERE data.International = TRUE) AS IntlAir
     , (SELECT sum(data.Penalty + data.SellingFare)
        FROM data
        WHERE data.International = FALSE) AS DomesticAir
FROM data
GROUP BY data.PostingMonth, data.DK_Number
ORDER BY data.PostingMonth;
```

However, the output is giving me the total sum across all dks and across all months, and putting this value into every row.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My suggestion, from experience; edit your post to include 5 or so records from your table called "data", 5 or so records from your result, and 5 or so records that your result SHOULD look like.  It will be a lot easier for us to help you if we can see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is all you need:

```
SELECT
    PostingMonth,
    DK_Number,
    SUM((Penalty + SellingFare) * IIf(International, 1, 0)) AS IntlAir,
    SUM((Penalty + SellingFare) * IIf(International, 0, 1)) AS DomAir
FROM [data]
GROUP BY PostingMonth, DK_Number
```

For the test data...

```
PostingMonth    DK_Number   International   Penalty SellingFare
------------    ---------   -------------   ------- -----------
1               1           False           $10.00  $100.00
1               1           True            $20.00  $200.00
2               1           False           $30.00  $300.00
1               2           False           $40.00  $400.00
1               2           False           $50.00  $500.00
1               2           True            $60.00  $600.00
```

...the above query returns

```
PostingMonth    DK_Number   IntlAir DomAir
------------    ---------   ------- -------
1               1           $220.00 $110.00
1               2           $660.00 $990.00
2               1           $0.00   $330.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do that, though the one you chose wasn't one of them

Never sure where access is at in terms of sql but if you create a query that does this and call it queryAirTotal or somesuch

```
SELECT PostingMonth, DK_Number, International, sum(Penalty + SellingFare) as AirTotal
FROM data GROUP BY PostingMonth,DK_Number,International
```

That will give your totals by month, dk and type then you can do

```
Select t1.PostingMonth,t1.DK_Number,t1.AirTotal as IntlAir, t2.Total as DomesticAir
From queryAirTotal t1
Left Join queryAirTotal t2 
On t1.PostingMonth = t2.PostingMonth and t1.DK_Number = t2.DK_Number
Where t1.International = TRUE and t2.International = FALSE
```

Though that will miss out Month/DKs where there was only Domestic air and no International air. You could sort that with a full outer join, which I believe access also struggles with.

You can get round that with a Union

```
Select t1.PostingMonth,t1.DK_Number,t1.AirTotal as IntlAir, t2.Total as DomesticAir
From queryAirTotal t1
Left Join queryAirTotal t2 
On t1.PostingMonth = t2.PostingMonth and t1.DK_Number = t2.DK_Number
Where t1.International = TRUE and t2.International = FALSE
Union
Select t1.PostingMonth,t1.DK_Number,t1.AirTotal as IntlAir, t2.Total as DomesticAir
From queryAirTotal t1
Left Join queryAirTotal t2 
On t2.PostingMonth = t1.PostingMonth and t2.DK_Number = t1.DK_Number
Where t1.International = TRUE and t2.International = FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - the response by Gord seemed to work; I haven't tried this yet but this would be great practice for unions and joins - I'm still a bit of an Access novice.

Comment: Nae problem, was never going to get the access way off me anyway.